# the best way to build a Business Application in .NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

We are building a new Business Application using .NET technologies.  First we started looking at some Javascript frameworks as we are basically converting a windows app to a web app so we thought using JS would give the same user experience as win forms.
We looked at many including Angular (no rich controls), KendoUI and WIJMO but ended up writing lots of JS and our prototype project became complicated as we used the SPA (Single page application) approach.

Is there is a way to get the simplicity of ASP.NET MVC and the great user experience of JS frameworks?  Has anyone had any experience with building a Business Application?  What are the recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: Angular is awesome for client side MVC.  If you also want UI elements you can use jQuery UI.  Angular does have some UI elements also, but not as many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we use a mixture of these technologies and a simple eventing strategy for communication between the server/client

- SignalR - for a persistent event pipe (transport)
- Angular - DOM manipulation/data binding
- Bootstrap - Great starting point.
- MVC - awesome asset pipe-lining in .net, allows for the bundling of lots of js files into one, and partials allow for sane management of a very componentized page structure.
- TypeScript - at scale js is very hard to maintain, refactor and debug, typescript removes an entire class of run-time errors and allows for very good code completion and refactoring tools in Visual Studio with ReSharper.

Comment: How do you handle MVC in the client (Angular) and the server (.NET MVC)?  Also you can use lots of other tools to concat javascript files into one like grunt, gulp, or require.js.

Comment: One other thing.  You can do your partial includes client side with `ng-include`.

Comment: So instead of doing a true SPA, we do several mini-SPAs, this is mainly just an organizational technique but could easily be done with ng-include as you mentioned, each of these lives at the traditional MVC URL server-side and has all of its components in partials.  As for the JS pipe-lining, using TypeScript its a seamless experience in Visual Studio and allows for things like conditional includes for debug that .net developers can leverage if they are already planning to use a .net platform

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Ext JS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) from [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/).

Ext JS uses an MVC architecture and has a whole bunch of nice user interface widgets.

**Disclaimer:** I am not affiliated with Sencha in any way. My company, however, does use their framework in our applications.